# Add X,Y coordinates to a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, coordinates, xy

I have x,y coordinates as excel file.
How can I add them into ArcMap?

Or - I have x,y coordinates of 2 points.
How can I quickly find them AND add/draw them on the map in ArcMap?

Comment: What version of ArcGis do you have?

Comment: ArcGis 9.3 version

Comment: I answered below...

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGis 9.3

Adding x,y coordinate data as a layer

Click the Tools menu and click Add XY Data.

Choose a table that contains x,y coordinate data. If the table is not on the map, click the Browse button to access it from disk.

Click the X Field drop-down arrow and click the field containing x-coordinate values.

Click the Y Field drop-down arrow and click the field containing y-coordinate values.

Click Edit to define the coordinate system and units represented in the x and y fields.

The x,y coordinates will be automatically transformed to match the coordinate system of the data frame.

Click OK.

In ArGis 10

You can search in searching dialog for the tool called Add XY event layer then follow the same below steps.

Answer (score 1):

**Importing Data**

There is a very extensive technical article, that can be found at the [ESRI Knowledge Base](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/index). The article covers version 9.x to 10.x:

"[Import XY data tables to ArcMap and convert the data to a shapefile](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/27589)"

As mentioned above, starting with ArcGIS 10 just use the "Add Data" tool from the main menu:

[image: Add Data ArcGIS 10.x]

**Adding Data**

For your second question please take a look into the ArcGIS Help, chapter:

[What is editing?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m500000003000000)

It is not so easy like putting a pushpin onto a Google map. There are more steps needed to archive what you want.

Comment: And from Excel I can export like usually or there is some specific data type in which I have to save?

Comment: @Kristine: what exactly do you mean by "export from Excel"?